# Spring Boot configure ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer in AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter - oAuth2

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

Im struggling with Spring Boot. I found great project on git hub and I am putting things together to understand what is happening. I have this piece of code and I don't understand what is doing:

```
@Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        clients
            .inMemory()
                .withClient("clientapp")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                    .authorities("USER")
                    .scopes("read", "write")
                    .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID)
                    .secret("123456");
        // @formatter:on
    }
```

what do I define with this inMemory()? and wihtClinet and so on... I don't get it, I would need some explanation, please.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Oauth2 authenticates client apps for some access types about user's information.

In your example, it configures a client app with name `clientapp`.

`inMemory` means all the necessary data to create a session will be stored in memory. When you restart your application, all the session data will be gone, which means users need to login and authenticate again.

Grant types represent the rights of the client app over user's information. In this case client app have rights to read and write user's `password` and `refresh_token`.

If you want to learn more of it you can take a look at [this](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/#_sso_with_oauth2_angular_js_and_spring_security_part_v) tutorial. You should also know what oAuth2 is.

Comment: _When you restart your application, all the session data will be gone_ ; when I start my app why would I restart server?

Comment: For example, you updated your code and re-deployed your app, all the session data will be gone.

Comment: yes that's true, but what is set inMemory will stay, right?

Comment: Nope. Your spring application is working on a JVM and when you restart it that JVM is also killed and re-created. This means your application makes a fresh start, all data in the memory is unreachable or freed. If you want to persist session data, you should store it in a database.

Comment: I don't know if we understand. The inMemory() inside ´configure method´ will stay, right?

Comment: It's just choice, if you want to keep them in memory it stays, otherwise if you want to keep them in database you could remove inMemory() method and put jdbc() method instead of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83984/discussion-between-5er-and-furkan3ayraktar).

Comment: Yes the configuration set in inMemory() will be loaded every time you run the app, but will be static, it will never change unless you recompile your application.

Comment: When you say the session data will be gone, what data is living in that session ? I thought all of this was stateless..

Comment: Also, I think the grant type is not the righs grated to the client application (this is expressed in the scope), but the method to access these.